# How do I perform operations according to the inner index of a multiIndex DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame of students' grades and want to track their grades with time. The DataFrame might look like this:

```
data = [ { "Name": "John", "Period": 1, "Grade": 60 }, { "Name": "John", "Period": 2, "Grade": 80 }, { "Name": "John", "Period": 3, "Grade": 90 }, { "Name": "Bill", "Period": 1, "Grade": 80 }, { "Name": "Bill", "Period": 2, "Grade": 70 }, { "Name": "Bill", "Period": 3, "Grade": 80 }, { "Name": "Tom", "Period": 1, "Grade": 50 }, { "Name": "Tom", "Period": 2, "Grade": 75 }, { "Name": "Tom", "Period": 3, "Grade": 50 } ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index(["Name", "Period"], inplace=True)

             Grade
Name Period       
John 1          60
     2          80
     3          90
Bill 1          80
     2          70
     3          80
Tom  1          50
     2          75
     3          50
```

Now I would like to add a "change" column that shows the percentage change from exam to exam. These are a bit like stacked DataFrames. If it were one, I would try something like

```
df["change"] = (df["Grade"] - df["Grade"].shift(1))/df["Grade"].shift(1)
```

This would correctly return a NaN value in the first row, since it has no previous value. Doing so on the above DataFrame yields:

```
             Grade    change
Name Period                 
John 1          60       NaN
     2          80  0.333333
     3          90  0.125000
Bill 1          80 -0.111111
     2          70 -0.125000
     3          80  0.142857
Tom  1          50 -0.375000
     2          75  0.500000
     3          50 -0.333333
```

Where I would like the first row's "change" value for each of the outer index values to be NaN, as below:

```
             Grade    change
Name Period                 
John 1          60       NaN
     2          80  0.333333
     3          90  0.125000
Bill 1          80       NaN
     2          70 -0.125000
     3          80  0.142857
Tom  1          50       NaN
     2          75  0.500000
     3          50 -0.333333
```

This is also so later when aggregating the "change" column, there are no wild shifts since one student's final grade affects the next student's first. I am aware that there are shortcuts where I can simply do the above transformation then change each of the first "change" values to np.nan, but feel there must be a more elegant method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.pct_change.html) by first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df["change"] = df.groupby(level=0)['Grade'].pct_change()
print (df)
             Grade    change
Name Period                 
John 1          60       NaN
     2          80  0.333333
     3          90  0.125000
Bill 1          80       NaN
     2          70 -0.125000
     3          80  0.142857
Tom  1          50       NaN
     2          75  0.500000
     3          50 -0.333333
```

Solution with [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
s = df.groupby(level=0)['Grade'].shift()
df["change"] = (df['Grade'] - s) / s

df["change"] =  df['Grade'].div(df.groupby(level=0)['Grade'].shift()).sub(1)
```

And with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df["change"] = df.groupby(level=0)['Grade'].apply(lambda x: (x - x.shift())/ x.shift())
```

Better:

```
df["change"] = df.groupby(level=0)['Grade'].apply(lambda x: (x / x.shift()) - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael. Are you able to modify this solution to show how I might do so with an apply function or some method that allows operations other than pct_change? I tried manually doing df["change"] = df.groupby(level=0)["Grade"].apply(lambda x: x-x.shift(1)) as a simple alternative (finding the arithmetic difference), but this did not work.